# Running a vm in ubuntu using shadow paging?

Tags: linux, x86, virtual-machine, intel, virtualization

In ubuntu, if you are running another ubuntu inside Virt-manger - what will be the effects of disabling nested paging and force using shadow paging on **the no. of VM exits**.  Will the counts of exits increase or decrease.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shadow paging always induces more exits than nested paging. Shadow paging may give better performance than nested paging only when the guest page tables are unusually static, so the cost of the additional VM exits is so low that it is less than the cost of nested translations.

Comment: is there a particular exits that will increase significantly than others- or is will all result in same proportional increase ?

Comment: Exits due to page faults, CR3 changes, and explicit TLB invalidations are the obvious ones that would increase. I wouldn't expect any increase in exit causes unrelated to paging, such as interrupt exits.